# Is the unity ball of $rba(X)$ a $G_{\delta}$ space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let be $S$ a metric space and $X=C_b(S)$ the set of all bounded continuous functions, then it's topological dual  $X^{\star}=rba(S)$ is the set of all regular Borel additive measures endowed with the variation norm.  Denote by $\mathscr{P}(X)$ the subset of $rba(X)$ of all  additive probability measures.

For a $G_{\delta}$ space I meant a space in which every closed set is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

**Question:** Is $\mathscr{P}(X)$  endowed with the weak topology a $G_{\delta}$ space? If not, is at least the singletons of  $\mathscr{P}(X),$ $G_{\delta}$  sets?

Comment: What is a $G_\delta$ space?  A space such that every closed set is $G_\delta$?

Comment: Exactly, this is the definition I meant

Comment: In my case $S$ is separable. I Know that in this case the space of all (countable additive ) probability measure is metrisable. In my case $\mathscr{P}(X)$ meant the set of all  additive measures, is  your  comment  in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I don't know. But my guess is that it's probably not true. If $S=\mathbf N$ with discrete metric, then $\mathscr P(X)$ looks like $\beta \mathbf N$. I'm not sure what the weak topology there looks like, though.